# Same method with two different names?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I wold like to use same method but two different names.

For example:

```
def func(a):
    print a

def func2(a):
    print a

n= "yes"
func(n)
func2(n)
```

answer should be:

```
"yes"
"yes"
```

Would there be any way I can do:

```
def fun(a) or func2(a):
    print a
```

or something like this?

Comment: If your function is something trivial as above, you could define it as a lambda and in-line both definitions. `func = func2 = lambda: print(a)` but be aware that this loses both readability and ease of modification (since lambdas are pretty limited in their use!) all to save a couple of lines of code. Not recommended!

Answer (score 11):

Python functions are just *objects*, you can assign one to another name:

```
def fun(a):
    print a

func2 = fun
```

Now the names `func2` and `fun` reference the same function object, you can call it through either name.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(a):
    print("a")

n= "yes"

def fun(a):
    func(a)

func(n)
```